# Permission Denied for fastcgi_pass using PHP7

Tags: nginx, php, php7

I'm running LEMP with PHP7.0.

I've got this in my server block

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
```

But when I open the site, it returns a 502 Bad Gateway. Below is the error log.

```
*1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP1.1", upstream: "fsatcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com"
```

It says *Permission Denied*. What's wrong here? I've checked but I can't seem to find what needs to be given what kind of permission.

Thank you.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I got it working.

The php user was `www-data` but the nginx user was `nginx`.

Check php here: /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
```

Nginx user was at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

This guided me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443398/nginx-error-connect-to-php5-fpm-sock-failed-13-permission-denied

Comment: You can change nginx to use _www-data_ user, or, as I did, add _nginx_ user to the _www-data_ group using `sudo usermod -a -G www-data nginx`

Answer (score 8):

I have fixed same issue by taking following steps.

Open your **www.conf** files (Example : sudo nano /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf)
Lastly, find the lines that set the listen.owner and listen.group and change their values from "nobody" to "nginx":

```
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660
```

Lastly, find the lines that set the user and group and change their values from "apache" to "nginx":

```
user = nginx
group = nginx
```

Restart php-fpm (sudo service php-fpm restart)

Comment: **listen.mode = 0666** - This is a massive security vulerability and exposes all data in the socket to all users.

Comment: @ NotoriousPyro may be you have good solution share here

Comment: The solution is don't use 0666

Answer (score 2):

```
vim /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
change in this way
;listen.owner = root
;listen.group = root
;listen.owner = nobody
;listen.group = nobody

listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx 

service php-fpm restart
service nginx restart

CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
```

Comment: Welcome on the site! It is an unexplained config snippet, I can't see how would it answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please **NOTICE** (**at least in centos 8**) the user who you are assigning `listen.owner` and other stuff to it **MUST**
be in the same **POOL** with the user for example given I am the **foo** user

```
[www] # WRONG | IN MY CASE I WAS UNDER www POOL SO IT WASNT WORKING FOR ME.
[foo] # CORRECT | THE POOL AND THE USER MATCHES.

listen.owner = foo
listen.group = foo
listen.mode = 0660
user = foo
group = foo
```

I dont know if there's a global pool but after hours of searching I finlly did it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user for the run nginx-process has permission for access to php-fpm socket.

So there is my configuration on the AWS.

I guess run php-process and nginx-pool as your user, not as root user.

[php-socket-own](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtIO4.jpg)

[nginx-config-user-run-pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weO8D.png)